# What do you call this WIFI sign

Tags: word-request

I live in university residence, and I have an internet problem. I am trying to send a message to the university to tell them about the problem. this is my email.

```
Dear Sir or Madam,

I am Marco Dinatsoli, an informatic-master-degree student.
I study at XXX and I live at: YYY
Room number ZZZ.

I live here since three weeks, and I have a big Internet problem.
The Internet in my room is too too slow and keeps disconnecting. I just have one WIFI signal, and in a very rarely cases, I have two signals.
Plus, when I open the window, the Internet almost stops working at all.
Moreover, every 20 minutes, the Internet disconnects.
I am 100% sure that the problem is not because of my laptop for the following reasons:

    I tried to connect to the WIFi from my laptop at another room in the building and the Internet works perfectly.
    I tried to connect to the WIFI from my friend's laptop at my room and it has the exact same problem.
    When I open the door of the room, the Internet becomes better.
    All the other rooms have a hardware above the door to improve the WIFI signal except my door.
    When I put my laptop in the hole (like far just 3 meters from my room), I have a very good Internet.

My room is the farthest room in the building, in front of it there is the kitchen, and beside it there is the washing machine room, that is why the problem happens just with me.

I am really really looking forward to your help as soon as possible because I have to study for the exam and for the practical work.

I count on your support.

Many thanks,
Best regards,
```

as you read, I stated that I have one WIFI signal, but I don't know if `Signal` is the correct word here.

I mean this :

[image]

Could you tell me please what is the correct word here?

Many thanks

Comment: Wifi signal is acceptable or you could say "wifi access point". However, I'm not sure what "laptop in the hole" means. Maybe because I am not there to understand this or maybe you could elaborate on that sentence.

Comment: @David I think he meant "hall".

Comment: Sounds like a good possibility. I wasnt sure. I was thinking like a 'cubby hole' (I know some dormitories have little cubby desks in the common areas.)

Comment: yes I am sorry, it is hall not hole :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question, and one that most native English speakers won't even get correct.

The icon you circled shows the **strength** or **quality** of your wifi signal as measured in **bars**.

Bars doesn't really mean much, though: it's not a regulated unit of measurement like grams or decibels. Different systems use different amounts of bars, so what's important is how many bars you have *out of* how many bars there are total.

You could say "My WiFi signal is very weak: only **2 out of 5 bars**."

And were it a better signal...

"My Wifi signal is okay: 3 out of 4 bars."

"My Wifi signal is really strong: full bars!"

Comment: What he circled was the strength but the sentence in about the number of connections in his room.

Comment: @David so should I use the `strenght` or the bar please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli i would use "wifi access point" if you are referring to how many places you can connect to. i would use "wifi strength" if you are referring to the quality of the particular "access point"

Comment: @David so I should say ` I just have one WIFI strength out of five, and in a very rarely cases, I have two strength out of five.` ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli - I would say something like - "The wifi strength is poor. Sometimes I have only one bar and rarely do I have two."

Comment: @David please do you see other problems? (except hole => hall)